# Passing pointer to template-function, when the template used as argument

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

While trying to play around with function pointers, I wondered if there's a way to pass as an argument a template-function pointer, which uses an instance of the template as one of its arguments. For example, I have the following template function:

```
template<class T>
bool match(int i, const T& M){
    return i%M.val==0;
}
```

which will eventually take the following class as T:

```
class Num{
public:
   int val;
   Num(int n): val(n) {}
};
```

(It's just a training code, I'm not using it for something of course)

Now, I have the following function, which is basically an implementation of count_if:

```
int countMod(const vector<int>& v, int mod, **???**){
  Num nMod(mod);
  int cnt=0;
  for(vector<int>::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end();it++){
    if(match(*it, nMod)){
        cnt++;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

The method is supposed to return the number of elements divisible by `mod`.
The third argument is the one I'm not sure about of course.

I want to somehow pass a pointer to the template function `match<Num>`, with `Num(mod)` as `M` .

I understand that it's quite weird to pass a pointer to something that doesn't actually exist, since I haven't instantiated an actual function, say match, 
but since the function `match` is supposed to get `const T&`, I'm really not sure how to sort it out, if possible.

Edit: 
I repaired the call to match as mentioned in the first comment, and yet I'm not sure what to pass as argument to `countMod`. I guess its something like  `bool(*match)(int, **???**)`, but I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler would be templatize your method

```
template <typename F>
int countMod(const vector<int>& v, int mod, F f)
{
  Num nMod(mod);
  int cnt = 0;
  for(vector<int>::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end();it++){
    if(f(*it, nMod)){
        cnt++;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

A more descriptive way would be

```
int countMod(const vector<int>& v, int mod, std::function<bool (int, Num)> f)
{
  Num nMod(mod);
  int cnt = 0;
  for(vector<int>::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end();it++){
    if(f(*it, nMod)){
        cnt++;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

and call it in both case

```
countMod(v, mod, &match<Num>);
```

Comment: You don't need a template in the second example, do you?

Comment: The second solution is indeed good, and I should read more about std:: function.
And yet, I wonder if there's a way to avoid the declaration of Num in the countMod's third arguement, and somehow pass the templated function it self, and let the compiler resolve it inside the method.

 For example, lets say there's another Class in addition to Num, name it Num2, and perhaps I want to instantiate the function passed in the third argument with both Num and Num2, inside the method countMod,
 but still use the passed template function as my base.

Comment: @kanabus: Indeed, typo of copy paste. Fixed.

Comment: It may be more descriptive, but it's generally less idiomatic as `std::function` has a significant runtime penalty. Usually only used when you specifically need type erasure.

Answer (score -1):

As you noted in the comment to Jarod42's answer, there's no real reason to pass in `mod`, because the only thing you do with `mod` is to feed it back to the function that's also getting passed in. So a logical thing to do is just to restructure your code:

```
template <typename F>
int count(const vector<int>& v, F f)
{
  int cnt = 0;
  for(vector<int>::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end();it++){
    if(f(*it)){
        cnt++;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

Now, you can just do the following:

```
int mod = 3; // or whatever
auto c = count(v, [nmod = Num(mod)] (int x) { return match(x, nmod); });
```

Note that this requires C++14, but you can easily modify it to work with 11. What we're doing now, is instead of passing the function directly, we use a lambda to bind one of the arguments before passing it in. This sort of thing is common when working with higher order functions.

Of course, you might notice at this point that `count` is looking really generic. It's really only non-generic in the container argument, insofar as it requires specifically a *vector* of *integers*. If we make that part generic too, we end up with a function in the standard library: `count_if`. Your problem can also be solved as:

```
auto c = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
           [nmod = Num(mod)] (int x) { return match(x, nmod); });
```